# JWT Auth getting Unauthenticated on request

Tags: laravel, api, jwt

I'm [using jwt-auth](https://github.com/tymondesigns/jwt-auth) to integrate with my system.

So I created a route group that uses jwt.auth middleware:

```
Route::group(['middleware' => 'jwt.auth'], function () {
  ...
});
```

But when I try to request one route from this group I'm getting this error:

```
{
    "error": "Unauthenticated."
}
```

On the request I'm passing the Authorization header with the Bearer and Token correct.

My Laravel version is 5.3

Jwt Config:

```
return [

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | JWT Authentication Secret
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Don't forget to set this, as it will be used to sign your tokens.
    | A helper command is provided for this: `php artisan jwt:generate`
    |
    */

    'secret' => env('JWT_SECRET', '****'),

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | JWT time to live
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Specify the length of time (in minutes) that the token will be valid for.
    | Defaults to 1 hour
    |
    */

    'ttl' => 60,

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Refresh time to live
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Specify the length of time (in minutes) that the token can be refreshed
    | within. I.E. The user can refresh their token within a 2 week window of
    | the original token being created until they must re-authenticate.
    | Defaults to 2 weeks
    |
    */

    'refresh_ttl' => 20160,

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | JWT hashing algorithm
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Specify the hashing algorithm that will be used to sign the token.
    |
    | See here: https://github.com/namshi/jose/tree/2.2.0/src/Namshi/JOSE/Signer
    | for possible values
    |
    */

    'algo' => 'HS256',

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | User Model namespace
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Specify the full namespace to your User model.
    | e.g. 'Acme\Entities\User'
    |
    */

    'user' => 'tracker\User',

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | User identifier
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Specify a unique property of the user that will be added as the 'sub'
    | claim of the token payload.
    |
    */

    'identifier' => 'id',

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Required Claims
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Specify the required claims that must exist in any token.
    | A TokenInvalidException will be thrown if any of these claims are not
    | present in the payload.
    |
    */

    'required_claims' => ['iss', 'iat', 'exp', 'nbf', 'sub', 'jti'],

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Blacklist Enabled
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | In order to invalidate tokens, you must have the blacklist enabled.
    | If you do not want or need this functionality, then set this to false.
    |
    */

    'blacklist_enabled' => env('JWT_BLACKLIST_ENABLED', true),

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Providers
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Specify the various providers used throughout the package.
    |
    */

    'providers' => [

        /*
        |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
        | User Provider
        |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
        |
        | Specify the provider that is used to find the user based
        | on the subject claim
        |
        */

        'user' => 'Tymon\JWTAuth\Providers\User\EloquentUserAdapter',

        /*
        |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
        | JWT Provider
        |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
        |
        | Specify the provider that is used to create and decode the tokens.
        |
        */

        'jwt' => 'Tymon\JWTAuth\Providers\JWT\NamshiAdapter',

        /*
        |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
        | Authentication Provider
        |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
        |
        | Specify the provider that is used to authenticate users.
        |
        */

        'auth' => 'Tymon\JWTAuth\Providers\Auth\IlluminateAuthAdapter',

        /*
        |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
        | Storage Provider
        |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
        |
        | Specify the provider that is used to store tokens in the blacklist
        |
        */

        'storage' => 'Tymon\JWTAuth\Providers\Storage\IlluminateCacheAdapter',

    ],

];
```

Appreciate your help.

Comment: We need more information here. What is the token being sent back, what is the token being sent out? We need to see the format. What does the JWT configuration look like?

Comment: I added the config of JWT, the token is correct... I tested with jwt.io

Comment: You're sure that namespace is right? Looks off to me.

Comment: Yes, checked all namespaces is correct...

Comment: me too facing same issue. Are you using JWT  ``"tymon/jwt-auth": "1.0.*"``? I think the doc is not clear for this. Awaiting for help too.